# ngMockE2E skipped when using addMockModule in Protractor test for mock requests

Tags: angular, protractor, ngmocke2e

Using Angular's Protractor framework, I have the following test file:

**storeItems.e2e.js:**

```
'use strict';
describe('home test', function() {
    beforeAll(function() {
        browser.addMockModule('httpMocker', function() {
            angular.module('httpMocker', ['ngMockE2E'])
                .run(function($httpBackend) { 
         $httpBackend.whenGET('/authentication/').respond([{"access_token": "123","expires_in": 500}]);
        })
      })
    })

    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

    it('should load page successfully', function() {
        browser.get('/store');
});
```

Running the above as a test doesn't seem to log any errors. However, when the browser loads, the network indicates that the request's response hasn't changed. And based on debugging/logging attempts, the code doesn't evaluate past `browser.addMockModule('httpMocker', function() {`

Also, I'm using Angular 1.7 so I believe that `addMockModule` should still be usable unlike v2+.

Answer (score 0):

When you navigate through `browser.get` , make sure that you have to use a full address, including protocol. For example: `browser.get('https://www.somesite.com')`